# Make HTML Table from List

Tags: python

So I have a list like this:

```
l = ['ID', 'Format', 'Width', 'Height', '\xc2\xa0', 'ID', 'Format', 'Width', 'Height', '0', 'original', 'original', 'original', '88', 'JPG', '247', '131', '1', 'JPG', '172', '128', '90', 'JPG', '240', '320']
```

I am trying to make a HTML table out of this list so that it looks like this:

[image: Image of Table]

As you can see, every 4th element is blank (starting with 0 as the index of the first element) and after every 8th element creates a new row. I tried this:

```
def reformat_html_id_table(line):
    htmlTable = '<table>\n'
    for i in range(0, len(line)):
        if (i < 0 and i % 3 == 0):
            htmlTable = htmlTable + '\t<td> </td>\n'

        elif i % 9 == 0:
            if i == 0:
                htmlTable = htmlTable + '<tr>\n'
            else:
                htmlTable = htmlTable + '</tr>\n<tr>\n'
            htmlTable = htmlTable + '\t<td>{0}</td>\n'.format(line[i])
        else:
            htmlTable = htmlTable + '\t<td>{0}</td>\n'.format(line[i])
    htmlTable = htmlTable + '</tr>\n</table>'
    print htmlTable
```

This yields:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Format</td>
    <td>Width</td>
    <td>Height</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Format</td>
    <td>Width</td>
    <td>Height</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>original</td>
    <td>original</td>
    <td>original</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>JPG</td>
    <td>247</td>
    <td>131</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>JPG</td>
    <td>172</td>
    <td>128</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>JPG</td>
    <td>240</td>
    <td>320</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Which is sortof correct, the first row is correct, but after that it doesn't and the blank data again and I am confused as to why. Can anyone show me what I did wrong? The expected output is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Format</td>
        <td>Width</td>
        <td>Height</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Format</td>
        <td>Width</td>
        <td>Height</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>original</td>
        <td>original</td>
        <td>original</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>88</td>
        <td>JPG</td>
        <td>247</td>
        <td>131</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>JPG</td>
        <td>172</td>
        <td>128</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>90</td>
        <td>JPG</td>
        <td>240</td>
        <td>320</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slightly modifying your own code, which was pretty good

```
def reformat_html_id_table(line):
    htmlTable = '<table>\n'
    mod = 9
    for i in range(0, len(line)):
        if (i > mod and i%mod == 5):
            htmlTable = htmlTable + '\t\t<td> </td>\n'
        if (i-9) % mod == 0:
            if i == 0:
                htmlTable = htmlTable + '\t<tr>\n'
            else:
                htmlTable = htmlTable + '\t</tr>\n\t<tr>\n'
            htmlTable = htmlTable + '\t\t<td>{0}</td>\n'.format(line[i])
        else:
            htmlTable = htmlTable + '\t\t<td>{0}</td>\n'.format(line[i])
        if i==9:
            mod=8
    htmlTable = htmlTable + '\t</tr>\n</table>'
    print htmlTable
```

It seemed to be a problem with having the first row of 9 elements and the rest of 8

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wasn't too far off by looking at your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to create HTML tables from list:

```
def print_table(data, row_length):
    print '<table>'
    counter = 0
    for element in data:
        if counter % row_length == 0:
            print '<tr>'
        print '<td>%s</td>' % element
        counter += 1
        if counter % row_length == 0:
            print '</tr>'
    if counter % row_length != 0:
        for i in range(0, row_length - counter % row_length):
            print '<td>&nbsp;</td>'
        print '</tr>'
    print '</table>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you do have the empty column in the first entry, but not in the second and third.

I kept it simple by deleting that element first and then just adding a blank td after the third column in each row:

```
def reformat_html_id_table(line):
    del(line[4]) # remove '\xc2\xa0'
    htmlTable = '<table>\n'

    for i in range(0, len(line)):
      posInRow = i % 8

      # begin row
      if (posInRow == 0):
        htmlTable += '<tr>'

      htmlTable += '\t<td>{0}</td>\n'.format(line[i])

      # add empty row
      if (posInRow == 3):        
            htmlTable += '\t<td> </td>\n'

      # end row
      if (posInRow == 7):
        htmlTable += '</tr>'

    htmlTable += '</table>'
    print htmlTable
```